# Does camel-elasticsearch 2.11.x not work remotely?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel

I am using the camel elasticsearch component : http://camel.apache.org/elasticsearch.html

My assumption, based on the docs, is that the elasticsearch server must be on the same network as the running camel route in order to work. Is this correct?

To clarify, the only connection property available is 'clustername'. I assume this is discovered by searching the network via multicast for the cluster.

My code needs to connect to a remote service. Is this just not possible?

I am fairly new to elasticsearch in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the autodiscovery of elasticsearch. I had a camel route that tried to index some exchanges, but the cluster was located in another subnet and thus not discoverd.

With the java api of ES it is possible to connect to a remote cluster with a TransportClient specifying an IP adress. I don't have acces to the code at the moment but the Java API in the ES documentation provides clean example code. You could make such a connection from within a bean in the route for example.

I also submitted a patch to Camel to add an ip parameter to the route, which should then connect to the remote cluster with such a TransportClient. The documentation states that should be available with Camel 2.12

Hope this helps.

Comment: Java API, as mentioned above: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/